# Apache2 forwarding to an old ddns server

Tags: apache2, self-hosting

I own a domain for a website (let's just use `"X.com"`), which for now I'm hosting on my home computer. This domain name points to my dynamic dns (`x.ddns.net`) name in the web forwarding of the domain name registrar as I have a dynamic ip and I haven't yet found a better way to make sure that the IP is consistently updated.

I recently changed the ddns address (`y.ddns.net`) and now whenever I try to access my site either from accessing the main domain name (`x.com`), or via typing in the local lan ip (`192.168.1.56`) I keep getting forwarded back to my original ddns address (`x.ddns.net`) and the website won't load.

I've looked through all the settings I can find both locally, with the ddns provider and with the (`x.com`) registrar to try to pin point where the forward takes place but I'm totally stuck.

Host system is Ubuntu, everything is up-to-date, nothing in `/etc/hosts` file pointing to the old ddns.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DDNS on Cloudflare](https://github.com/nikhiljohn10/ddns-on-cloudflare)

Only problem is that you need to move your domain to cloudflare dns servers which is totally free to use.